# Getting column information from a sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, rest, client-object-model

I'm trying to figure out how i can get information about a column in a Sharepoint List, like what type of column it is (single line, number, date etc...) and whatever additional column info that column may also have

i was looking for a way to do it using Javascript and REST in Sharepoint 2010, is it even possible? if not with REST calls, would the client side object model be the only way to achieving this?

any help would be great.

Thank You